# Landing card, transit visa in Kuala Lumpur

Tags: transit-visas, tips-and-tricks, malaysia, sri-lankan-citizens

I am a Sri Lankan traveling from Colombo to Manila. I have a layover of 2 hours in Kuala Lumpur. Do I need to fill out a landing card? Do I need a transit visa? Same airline from Sri Lanka to Kuala Lumpur to Manila, Philippines.

Comment: Hi ken and welcome to Travel.SE. I made some minor edits and added tags to your question. Feel free to change it back if this doesn't reflect what you wanted to ask.